# when try to cd, tab can not switch different folder options when using oh my zsh

Tags: oh-my-zsh

Questions:
when try to cd ,  tab once will show directories options
[image]

but tap once again ,it will just enter the first folder like this ,not switch between them

[image]

if I continue press tab , it will just show the content in the first folder

How can I use tab to switch between different folder options ??

the version of zsh is 5.9, btw ,the system version of ubuntu is 23.04 beta.